# Am I drawing the recursion trees correctly?

Tags: recursion

I guess I've already figured out what is a recursion tree and how to construct one. Inspired by Figure 2.5 of "Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition by CLRS", I drew some recursion trees for the recurrence $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + cn$.

the recursion tree for the recurrence when n=16

[image]

the recursion tree for the recurrence when n=13

[image]

the recursion tree for the recurrence when n=7

[image]

Could someone help double-check my understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T(n/2)$ is not well-defined if $n$ is odd.  The merge sort recurrence - if you want to take floors and ceilings into account - is actually $T(n) = T(\lceil n/2 \rceil) + T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + cn$.  So, if $n=13$, the subproblems would have sizes $7$ and $6$, respectively (not $8$ and $5$, respectively).

It’s ok to be sloppy and assume $n$ is a power of $2$ because that doesn’t affect the final conclusions.  Recursion trees are usually drawn with this simplifying assumption, and the intuition carries over to the general case.